# How can I redirect to 404.php when the page doesn't really exist?

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, errordocument

I have this 404 redirection in my .htaccess file :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

It works fine when I try to access a page that doesn't really exist on my server.

The problem is that when I return my own HTTP 404 status in a page that really exists on the server, it doesn't redirect me to the 404.php page, but the browser displays a standard 404 error.

I return my own HTTP 404 status when I have a wrong url parameter for example.

Can you help me to define the rule in the .htaccess file, please?

Comment: No, it's not the same thing Juakali92

Answer (score 1):

in your `.htaccess` file you should have this rule

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

and if you want to simulate this error in anyplace other than typing it manually in the header you should use [http_response_code](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php)

PHP code

```
<?php
    http_response_code(404);
    include('my_404.php'); // provide your own HTML for the error page
    die();
```